# Ruby on Rails - change value of the price in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am getting all products through Active reocrd

```
@results = Product.all
```

Now I want to multiply every "price" value to "price*100" 
how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
@results = Product.all.select("*, `price` * 100 AS `price`")
```

or

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price
    super * 100
  end
end
```

or

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def cents
    price * 100
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual attribute to app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def price_in_cents  # or some other appropriate name
    price * 100
  end
  ...
end
```

And use it as something like @results.first.price_in_cents